# XPages - SSJS calling a bean

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am attempting to call some java code from an XPage and was attempting to do this via SSJS.  Just trying to get even a basic hello world example working.  Ideally the return from the java code could be stuffed into a variable.

Goal: (Xpage contents)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:label value="#{javascript:helloWorld.anyoneThere}" id="label1"></xp:label>
</xp:view>
```

would print 'Yo!' when the page loads.  Instead I get a Runtime Error that helloWorld is not found.

Created a package

```
package testBean;

public class helloWorld {
    public String anyoneThere(){
        return "Yo!";
    }
}
```

Then I modified the faces-config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>helloWorld</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>testBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

Not sure what I need to do to initialize / call the java function.  Some examples I've seen are hooking into views or are on events but the intended code for what I'm doing would more likely be run in the beforePageLoad section.

Comment: Both answers have pointers to get your sample working. I'd want to suggest to also follow the standard Java naming standards and start you Class name with an uppercase letter, e.g. HelloWorld. Also, make your class serializable ("public class HelloWorld implements Serializable") which is a requirement for beans.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your managed-bean-class has you include the class name as well.

```
<managed-bean-class>testBean.helloWorld</managed-bean-class>
```

Also your label has to have parenthesis

```
<xp:label value="#{javascript:helloWorld.anyoneThere();}" id="label1"></xp:label>
```

Comment: Hi Toby, I tried it both ways but wasn't sure if I was supposed to add that as another line to the faces or if I was supposed to just modify the existing one.  Regardless the new error is [ReferenceError] 'helloWorld' not found.  This is the bit I'm trying to wrap my head around - how to initialize and access these new objects/beans.

Comment: It should replace the original line.  It should be able to find helloWorld once that it changed.  The other thing I would say you definetly want to do is in Designer from the menu go to Project -> Build Project.  This will ensure that the class gets compiled.

Comment: <facepalm>I have the same project open on a prod and dev server and the Package Explorer view switched the order.  So I put the bean and faces changes on the prod server while the XPage was on the dev server instead of everything on the dev.  crud! I was able to get it working with your tips as I still needed to make all the changes you listed.  Thanks for the help Toby!

Answer (score 2):

I have written a [small tutorial on the basics of creating and using a simple managed bean with XPages](http://per.lausten.dk/blog/2012/02/creating-your-first-managed-bean-for-xpages.html).

The tutorial also shows how to add getters and setters to your variables so that you can use EL to reference them. So in your example you will be able to do the following to reference the `anyoneThere` variable (assuming that you have set up a getter and setter for it):

```
<xp:label value="#{helloWorld.anyoneThere}" id="label1"></xp:label>
```

Comment: This is a crucial point. If a Java class isn't a set of properties exposed via getters and setters, it's not actually a bean... it's a POJO (Plain Old Java Object). Java beans are Java classes that conform to the getter/setter convention and, as Mark mentioned, implement the Serializable interface.

Comment: Hi Per, your tutorial was one of the first items I found when I started out.  The tutorial didn't have an example to call the helloWorld item beyond  #{helloWorld.someVariable}, and when I tried to do just what you listed above it never returned anything to the page.  I tried hardcoding the return (so there was something there) but it was still blank. 


@TimTripcony - I previously had them but was gutting this example for simplicity sake.  I will make sure to follow the convention on the real examples.  Thanks for the reminder.